# BASH script to check for two mounted drives 'unary operator expected'

Tags: bash, shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Trying to write a bash script that will check for two mounted drives then do something if both are connected. So far I've got:

```
if [ $(mount | grep -c /media/card) != 1 ]
 then
    echo "ERROR: SD card not mounted"
    sudo sh -c "echo timer > /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger"
    sudo sh -c "echo 2000 > /sys/class/leds/led0/delay_on"
else
    if [ $(mount | grep -c /media/backup) !=1 ]
    then
            echo "ERROR: Backup not mounted"
            sudo sh -c "echo timer > /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger"
            sudo sh -c "echo 2000 > /sys/class/leds/led0/delay_on"
    else
            echo "All Plugged in"
    fi
fi
```

Running returns the error:

```
./backup2.sh: line 12: [: 0: unary operator expected
```

Not sure why the first `if` statement works, but then the second doesn't, as they basically the same. Is there a cleaner way of checking for two mounted devices? Ideally outputting an error showing which one(s) aren't mounted.

Comment: PS: [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) automatically points out the missing space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a space after the `!=`:

> ```
> if [ $(mount | grep -c /media/backup) !=1 ]
> ```

Like this:

```
if [ $(mount | grep -c /media/backup) != 1 ]
```

Btw, what happens if you have more than 1 mounted drives matching `/media/card` or `/media/backup`?
The output will be misleading,
saying that "X is not mounted".

So it seems it would make more sense to replace the `!= 1` conditions with `== 0`.
But if you decide to do that,
then there's a better way to write the conditions,
using the exit codes of the pipelines directly.

```
if ! mount | grep /media/card >/dev/null
then
    echo "ERROR: SD card not mounted"
    sudo sh -c "echo timer > /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger"
    sudo sh -c "echo 2000 > /sys/class/leds/led0/delay_on"
elif ! mount | grep /media/backup >/dev/null
then
    echo "ERROR: Backup not mounted"
    sudo sh -c "echo timer > /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger"
    sudo sh -c "echo 2000 > /sys/class/leds/led0/delay_on"
else
    echo "All Plugged in"
fi
```

Comment: Sorry janos -- you just beat me on the *elif* ... :-)

Comment: Thank you, this works! It's unlikely that it'll ever have more than one in the same place, as I'm using this to create a portable backup device for my camera SD card.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little cleaner code -- removed the nested `if` and used `elif` instead as well as taken into account `janos` remark about the space needed at `!=1`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $(mount | grep -c /media/card) != 1 ]
then
    echo "ERROR: SD card not mounted"
    sudo sh -c "echo timer > /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger"
    sudo sh -c "echo 2000 > /sys/class/leds/led0/delay_on"
elif [ $(mount | grep -c /media/backup) != 1 ]
then
    echo "ERROR: Backup not mounted"
    sudo sh -c "echo timer > /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger"
    sudo sh -c "echo 2000 > /sys/class/leds/led0/delay_on"
else
    echo "All Plugged in"
fi
```

Seems to work well under Red Hat 6.x